# Exploiting JavaScript's eval() method

Tags: javascript, security, eval, client-side, code-injection

Many developers believe that JavaScript's `eval()` method should be avoided. This idea makes sense from a design perspective. It is often used as an ugly workaround when a simpler, better option is available.

However, I do not understand the concerns about security vulnerabilities. Certainly, running `eval()` gives the hacker the ability to run any JavaScript code that you can run.

But can't they do this anyway? In Chrome, at least, the Developer Tools allow the end-user to run their own JavaScript. How is `eval()` more dangerous than the Developer Tools?

Comment: That's not *"the common consensus"*. Many experienced developers are annoyed by the FUD about `eval`. The *"eval is evil"* is probably never said today by experienced coders. If you're stupid, it may be dangerous. But usually it's just slow, ugly and leading to hard to evolve code.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I think mozilla devs can be considered experienced. This [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) suggests to avoid eval and use Function instead, which they claim is faster and also safer since it can only access the global scope.

Comment: @N4ppeL Of course most usually there are better alternatives to `eval`. I told it (read my comment to the end). My point is that *"eval is evil"* might be a fun slogan but isn't a useful take. BTW it could be argued that JS did change a little since 2013 so trying to revive and debate an old conversation is probably best left to historians.

Comment: I strongly disagree with that last part, since people still end up here looking for advice, so the debate should absolutely be kept up to date. Which is also why I wanted to point to a potential alternative, although of course also `Function` should only be used with care as well. If possible, a JSON-parser or similar should be used instead. There is also [a more recent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil) discussing this topic that might be of interest for anyone ending up here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As B-Con mentioned, the attacker is not the one sitting at the computer so could be using the `eval()` already in your script as a means to pass malicious code to your site in order to exploit the current user's session in someway (e.g. a user following a malicious link).

The danger of `eval()` is when it is executed on unsanitised values, and can lead to a [DOM Based XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS) vulnerability.

e.g. consider the following code in your HTML (rather contrived, but it demonstrates the issue I hope)

```
<script>

eval('alert("Your query string was ' + unescape(document.location.search) + '");');

</script>
```

Now if the query string is `?foo` you simply get an alert dialog stating the following: `Your query string was ?foo`

But what this code will allow a user to do is redirect users from their site to a URL such as `http://www.example.com/page.htm?hello%22);alert(document.cookie+%22`, where www.example.com is your website.

This modifies the code that is executed by `eval()` to

```
alert("Your query string was hello");
alert(document.cookie+"");
```

(New lines added by me for clarity). Now this could be doing something more malicious than showing the current cookie value, as the required code is simply passed on the query string by the attacker's link in encoded form. For example, it could be sending the cookie to the attacker's domain in a resource request, enabling the authentication session to be hijacked.

This applies to any value from user/external input that is unsanitised and executed directly in the `eval()`, not just the query string as shown here.

Comment: This makes sense. I was thinking that `eval()` allowed hacking into the website itself, rather than allowing other sites to scrape user data.

Comment: Not directly, but it could do if an admin user was targeted.

Answer (score 6):

An attacker doesn't have access to the user's browser's Developer Tools. The attacker is likely not the user sitting at the computer.

The danger of `eval()` is that an attacker may be able to manipulate data that is eventually run through `eval()` in other ways. If the `eval()`'d string comes from an HTTP connection, the attacker may perform a MITM attack and modify the string. If the string comes from external storage, the attacker may have manipulated the data in that storage location. Etc.

Comment: The real problem is the string coming from any source that is user supplied.  MITM attack will always be a problem, regardles of `eval`.  If they are doing MITM, they can modify the regular non-evaled JS payload just as easily.

Comment: Another classic example is `eval`ing GET variables is an easy way to open XSS holes. Etc.