# Content Security Policy (CSP) - safe usage of unsafe-eval?

Tags: content-security-policy

We use the following CSP header:

```
default-src 'self' *.ourdomain.com; script-src 'self' *.ourdomain.com 'sha256-[...]' 'unsafe-eval'; 
connect-src 'self' *.ourdomain.com; 
style-src 'unsafe-inline' * 'self' data:; font-src *; 
img-src * 'self' data:
```

The recommendation by our security team is not use unsafe-eval.

My question is: as long as we are using **sha256-[...]** to restrict any script that we haven't deployed ourselves, what is the security risk of still keeping **unsafe-eval** in the CSP header? In what situation would this still expose us to cross-site attacks?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because eval is literally unsafe. Eval in every language means "take this string and execute it code."  Sure, you may be using eval in a semi-safe way, but as long as you allow it at all, you are saying "anyone is allowed to execute arbitrary code in my application given an entry point".

**2022 edit**: the section below has not stood the test of time and things like WASM require `unsafe-eval`. It's still true that many front end frameworks still require `unsafe-eval` too.

> It is my **opinion** that there is no reason to use eval. Show me a case where eval is **required** in actual useful code and I'll bet that I can rewrite the code without using eval or declare it as impossibly secure code.

Disallowing Inline script is only half the battle, especially if you use jquery.

Quiz: does this code trigger an inline script violation or an eval violation?

```
$('body').html('<script>alert(1)</script>')
```

You may be surprised.

Spoiler:

> it's eval (at the time this was written)

Comment: There is a reason: performance. It is nearly impossible to build an interpreter that is as fast as compiled code. Using `eval()` allows faster code in cases when the code depends on some runtime data. For a more specific use case, consider a site in which user supplies URL to data, and an arbitrary expression into that data. The expression would need to be evaluated millions of times. Doing it interpretively (e.g. expression "a.b.c" is converted into an array ['a','b','c'], and loop to access child of a child of a child object) is clearly slower than x=eval('(a) => a.b.c') and call x(a).

Comment: @yurik yes, performance is absolutely a reason. I don’t have any data to back it up, but I feel the performance gain won’t be meaningful in many cases. People used to eval JSON instead of parsing it, but the trade off just wasn’t worth it to many.

Comment: I think eval(json) and JSON.parse() are comparable in performance, but if you have a large json, I'm sure doing a manual parsing (without the JSON.parse) would be much slower.

Comment: I’m trying to avoid absolute statements, especially around something as complicated as csp, but it is still my opinion that the risk is not worth the gain. But I do want to reiterate that disabling eval is not performant for some.

Comment: Fair enough. Initial JS implementations were interpreters, but later they became compilers of JS to native CPU instructions. Did that make them safer? Probably not, but it clearly gained in performance. We all demand fast JS, even though internally browsers basically use "eval" on JS code to make it native. So they do a lot of careful checks, and sandboxing using CPU features, all to gain both the speed and security.

Comment: Also, the `unsafe-eval` is needed to use the WASM, for now.

Comment: Show me a case where eval is required and I'll bet that I can rewrite the code without using eval or declare it as impossibly secure code:  
    function check() {
        try { eval("class = {}"); }
        catch (e) { return false; }
        return true;
    }

Comment: I believe there is no other way than using eval/Function for some feature detections, e.g. for generators and async/await.

Comment: No matter how much I beat on our scripts, jquery and other 3rd party libraries we use, still somehow keep tripping an `eval` that gets blocked by CSP. Without rewriting someone ELSES code (defeating the purpose of using said libraries)... we are just at a loss, and throwing our hands up and adding `unsafe-eval` to our definition.

Comment: Underscore uses `new Function` which is also blocked by CSP for same reason: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L915

Comment: maybe this was the case when this was written, but that no longer evaluates as unsafe-eval, it is an unsafe-inline

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that @XRBtoTheMOON, I've updated the spoiler.

Comment: _Show me a case where eval is required in actual useful code and I'll bet that I can rewrite the code without using eval_

@oreoshake How could I write this without `eval`?  
`var supportsEs6 = function (){  try {new Function("(x = 0) => a");return true}catch(e){ return false}}();`

Comment: One more reason: Flutter. Flutter web canvaskit works based on it. :(

Answer (score 5):

The security risk is that it doesn't protect any of your own code that may be vulnerable because `eval` is used.

If you are using `eval` in your own code you should question why. Is there a safer alternative that can be employed instead?

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18208029/413180) for a (contrived) example of how code can be injected by an attacker. Of course whether this can be done to your site very much depends on your code.

The upshot is that there's almost always an alternative to using `eval`.

Comment: Can I call you on that bet please, we use the KendoUI which uses eval() in it's templating