# Is there any way to fix 'unsafe-eval' of Content-Security-Policy in our website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, content-security-policy

I have around 50+ files in which `eval()` function is used. Most of it are JS libraries such as `jquery`, `datepicker`, `thickbox`, `buttons`, `timepicker`. How can I fix this?

I tried strict CSP, but it stops `jquery`, website layouts gets changed, and some functionalities stopped working.

This is what I have:

```
header(
  "Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';  " .
  "object-src 'none'; ".
  "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com *".str_replace('www','', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])."; ".
  "script-src  'self'  'nonce-".$_SESSION['token_csp']."' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google.com/recaptcha/  https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/; " .
  "font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'  fonts.gstatic.com ; " .
  "frame-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: https://www.google.com/  *.youtube.com *.youtube-nocookie.com; " .
  "img-src https: data:; " .
  "base-uri 'self'; ".
  "form-action 'self'; ".
  "child-src 'self'; ".
  "media-src *.google.com *.youtube.com; ".
  "frame-ancestors 'none'; ".
  "connect-src *; "
    // "report-uri https://3c72f406c71f6c7c8e8f8dff8658bd09.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce; "
);
```

Comment: The point of the stricter CSP is to eliminate all uses of `eval`. That can be only be achieved by rewriting all your code to not use `eval`.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155270/content-security-policy-csp-safe-usage-of-unsafe-eval