# Using CSP with a library using unsafe-eval

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

I am trying to implement CSP in my Angular project. My CSP is as below;

```
script-src 'self' 'nonce-anything';
style-src 'self' 'nonce-anything' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;
upgrade-insecure-requests;
block-all-mixed-content;
```

One of the libraries I am using (json-logic-engine) is using eval function, that's why I can't make it run without 'unsafe-eval'. I thought nonce attribute on scripts would allow evals, but according to my recent research, it only allows unsafe-inline - not unsafe-eval.

[image: 1]

Is there any way to fix it without using 'unsafe-eval'?

Answer (score 0):

> Because eval is literally unsafe. Eval in every language means "take this string and execute it code." Sure, you may be using eval in a semi-safe way, but as long as you allow it at all, you are saying "anyone is allowed to execute arbitrary code in my application given an entry point".

from [questions 37155270](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155270/content-security-policy-csp-safe-usage-of-unsafe-eval)

Because of this point, you only have three options: basically substitute this eval call following some security options (that is, not all cases), preprocess this, and use 'unsafe-inline'.

You can see better on this web.dev article: [web.dev csp eval](https://web.dev/articles/csp#eval_too)