# How to convert math operation in string to int? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mathematical-optimization

Can anybody tell me how to convert math operation which is in string to int and get the result?
For example give string "2 + 3 * 4 - 5" to function and get correct result. Any tips how to do it?

Thank You :)

I tried to use split and join method but nothing good happend

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077923/how-can-i-convert-a-string-into-a-math-operator-in-javascript) be of help?

Comment: I think what you want to do is use eval() as @Tommi is suggesting. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build an abstract syntax tree (AST) and iterate over the tree to get the result.

For example: you can build a tree for an expression `"2 + 5 x 4"` as follows

[image]

Learn more about [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)

### Extra:

JS AST [implementation](https://www.esimovmiras.cc/articles/03-build-math-ast-parser/) for math expressions

[Math.js](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html) has lots of functionalities for parsing math expressions

you can also use JS `eval()` function but it has some [security concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189496/exploiting-javascripts-eval-method)

Cheers!